# Determining the strength of information to vote for candidates.

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose you are trying to decide which of two candidates to vote for. You think there is a 60% chance that Candidate A is better than Candidate B. Then, you hear a news report that claims B is better than A.
>
> a)Assuming you vote for whichever candidate you think is most likely to be better, how accurate does the information have to be for you to vote for Candidate B? [Hint: use ‘p’ to capture the accuracy of the news report]
>
> b) Now, suppose that you receive an additional piece of information after hearing the news report: your friend tells you that she thinks A is better than B. How accurate does her information have to be for you to vote for Candidate A? Your answer will be in terms of ‘p’. [Hint: use ‘q’ to capture the accuracy of your friend’s information]

I'm not very good at probabilities, but for the first part, I was thinking that we have to determine a $p$ such that $.6*p=.5 \implies p=5/6 \approx 83.3 %$.  So the new information that we hear has to be $83.3%$ true.

For the second part, assuming the first part is correct, we do the same procedure to get $.6*p*q=.5 \implies q=\frac{5}{6p}$

Are these calculations correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It rather depends on how $p$ and $q$ are stated.  What you would like is the likelihood of the reports saying A if A is better and of saying A is B is better, and of similarly of saying B if B is better and of saying B is A is better

Suppose for the newspaper, it says B is better when B is indeed better with conditional probability $p$ and it says B is better when A is better with conditional probability $1-p$.  These do not have to add up to one, though will do if the newspaper is unbiased

Then your revised view of the possibility of A being better, combining your previous view and the newspaper could be $\dfrac{0.6(1-p)}{0.6(1-p)+0.4p} =  \dfrac{3-3p}{3-p}$.  You might then vote for B when this expression is less than $\frac12$, which would require $p \gt \frac35$

This makes some kind of intuitive sense: you might change your vote if you think the newspaper is more accurate than you.

Now take into account your friend's view and similarly suppose she says A is better when A is indeed better with conditional probability $q$ and she says A is better when B is better with conditional probability $1-p$. Then you can update your opinion again, either with  $\dfrac{0.6(1-p)q}{0.6(1-p)q+0.4p(1-q)}$ or with    $\dfrac{\frac{3-3p}{3-p}q}{\frac{3-3p}{3-p}q +\left(1-\frac{3-3p}{3-p}\right)(1-q)}$, both of which simplify to $\dfrac{3pq-3q}{5pq-2p-3q}$ as your re-revised view of the possibility of A being better

That will greater than $\frac12$ if $q \gt \frac{2p}{3-p}$ at which point you switch back to supporting A. As a simple check, that cannot happen when $p=1$; meanwhile $p=q$ otherwise leads to you original value of $0.6$ since the newspaper and your friend balance each other out